# Design: Visit meta box has the wrong colour cues

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "Visit meta" box on the front page has the wrong colour cues. It looks like a series of `blockquotes`, instead of a series of links to meta questions.

[image: Visit meta]

Comment: this has been edited to be changed to a grey.

Comment: Sorry still there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the next build. Thanks for your help. Link colors changed in meta feature module.